# How does an accountant estimate the salvage value of an asset when calculating depreciation?

Tags: accounting, depreciation

I'm studying the very basics of accounting, so bear with me please :)

When calculating depreciation using the straight line method for example, one takes the cost of the asset, estimates the salvage value of the asset, and fits a straight line between these two points over the useful life of the asset.

Let's say a small company buys a computer. The cost of the asset is easy, as this is just the buying price of the computer. But how does whoever doing the accounting estimate the scrap/salvage value of the computer? I would imagine this would be very computer specific, and estimating it would require expert knowledge on computers. Same for the useful life of the computer, these also vary a lot. How would somebody without expert knowledge on the workings of a particular asset estimate these kinds numbers?

Answer (score 1):

In accounting, the "value" of anything is what people in a free market are typically willing to pay. So to estimate the scrap value of an asset, we look at what scrap dealers or recyclers or used equipment dealers typically pay. If this is a big company that is routinely buying new equipment and disposing of old equipment, we look at what we have gotten for similar old equipment in the past. If we don't have any experience with this type of item, we call a scrap dealer and ask or find a website or other reference that lists scrap prices.

Similarly for useful life. You don't have to be an expert in computer engineering to estimate the useful life of a computer. Just look at how long similar computers have lasted in the past. If they've lasted an average of, say, 5 years, then you write down 5 years. You don't need to have any idea at all why it might start to fail after 5 years. You certainly don't have to know how one might design a computer that would last longer. You just use the empirical numbers.

And realistically, if we expect the scrap value to be too trivial to be worth the effort of doing the research, we make up something that seems plausible. It is, after all, an "estimate", not a number that we are committing to. We don't want to record the scrap value of a machine as $10,000 if it turns out it's really more like $20. But if it's really $22 and we write $20, then unless we have thousands of them it's probably not a big deal.